# type error:flow property is missing in undefined [1]

Tags: fetch, flowtype, use-effect

Hi I build a single page app to search by name,while I input any character in search bar there appear to be type error,so I use `FLOW` to check and down below are two errors.I was told`incompatible-use`,but what is right use,anyone could give me some document to read?

> 

```
Error -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/component/List.js:22:25
Cannot get `data.students` because property `students` is missing in undefined [1]. [incompatible-use]

   src/component/List.js:22:25
   22|     const newarr = data.students.map(student => {
                               ^^^^^^^^

References:
   src/component/List.js:10:27
   10|   const [data, setData] = useState();
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^ [1]


Error -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- src/component/List.js:68:31
Cannot build a typed interface for this module. You should annotate the exports of this module with types. Missing type
annotation at function return: [signature-verification-failure]
```

Below is my code:

```
// @flow
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

function User({ login }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!login) return;
    fetch(`https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/${login}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(setData)
      .catch(console.error);
  }, [login]);

  const handleNameSearch = (e) => {
    const newarr = data.students.map((student) => {
      if (
        student.firstName.toUpperCase().includes(e.target.value.toUpperCase())
      )
        return student;
      else if (
        student.lastName.toUpperCase().includes(e.target.value.toUpperCase())
      )
        return student;
      else return null;
    });
    const result = newarr.filter((student) => student !== undefined);
    setData({ students: result });
  };

  if (data)
    return [
      <Paper
        style={{
          maxWidth: 600,
          maxHeight: 300,
          marginLeft: 300,
          marginRight: 300,
          marginBottom: 10,
        }}
      >
        <TextField
          onChange={handleNameSearch}
          id="standard-basic"
          label="Search by name"
          style={{ width: 600 }}
        />
      </Paper>,
      <div>
        {data.students.map((student, index) => {
          const newgrades = student.grades.map((x) => +x);
          return (
            <Paper
              key={student.id}
              style={{
                maxWidth: 600,
                maxHeight: 300,
                marginLeft: 300,
                marginRight: 300,
              }}
            >
              <Grid container spacing={1}>
                <Grid item style={{ marginTop: 50, marginRight: 0 }}>
                  <Avatar style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}>
                    <img
                      src={student.pic}
                      alt="avatar"
                      style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                    />
                  </Avatar>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item style={{ marginLeft: 30 }}>
                  <h1>{student.firstName + " " + student.lastName}</h1>
                  <section>
                    <p>Email:{student.email}</p>
                    <p>Company:{student.company}</p>
                    <p>Skill:{student.skill}</p>
                    <p>
                      Average:
                      {newgrades.reduce(
                        (accumulator, currentValue) =>
                          accumulator + currentValue,
                      ) / newgrades.length}
                      %
                    </p>
                  </section>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Paper>
          );
        })}
      </div>,
    ];

  return null;
}

export default function List() {
  return <User login="students" />;
}
```

I also create in the link to help my helpers to test or play:https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-cache-2swtl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace`setData({ students: result });`with `setData(() => { return { students: result } })`   and replace const result = newarr.filter((student) => student !== undefined); with `const result = newarr.filter((student) => student !== null);`within `handleNameSearch` .the live search Works well

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because when `data` is initialised in the `useState()` call, it is undefined, if you were to run `handleNameSearch` immediately you'll find that it would crash because `data` is undefined, as your flow error says, so then `data.students` would crash, and flow is throwing an error to prevent this.

There are a number of ways to prevent this, either you `return null` early above the creation of your `handleNameSearch` function though this is probably wrong given what you're trying to accomplish as a filter.

I doubt the rest of your logic would function properly if we simply ignore this error though so to get you by, I would suggest you just do the simplest thing and only run the code block if data is populated

```
  const handleNameSearch = (e) => {
    if (!data) return;

    const newarr = data.students.map((student) => {
      if (
        student.firstName.toUpperCase().includes(e.target.value.toUpperCase())
      )
        return student;
      else if (
        student.lastName.toUpperCase().includes(e.target.value.toUpperCase())
      )
        return student;
      else return null;
    });
    const result = newarr.filter((student) => student !== undefined);
    setData({ students: result });
  };
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it did not work,I also doubt usestate does not update state sync so I replace `setData({ students: result });`with `setData(() => { return { students: result } });` within`handleNameSearch`.my solution was inspired by `https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do ` and `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately`.I will search more material to share with you,thanks